# Given a weekday name, week of a month, and a year, how to find the date

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, date

I can find the last Monday using `date -d 'last-monday' +%F` but given a weekday name, week of a month, and a year, how to find the date?

e.g. given: `Monday, Week 4, June, 2022`
output: `2022-06-20`

given: `Friday, Week 1, July, 2022`
output: `2022-07-01`

Comment: How is the "week of a monh" counted?

Comment: guessing first day of week is Sunday, it comes from 3rd party system

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: So, Monday, Week 1, June, 2022 would give 2022-05-30, right?

Comment: Monday, Week 1, June, 2022 would be an invalid date, but you got the point. Monday, Week 2, June, 2022 would be 2022-06-06

Comment: What should the output be if an invalid date is given?

Comment: was looking for some bash solution using `date`, so would return `date: invalid date ''`

Comment: A bash solution using date would be immensely slow, I doubt anyone would recommend that.

Comment: You don't actually say it, but I assume the month itself is also given?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following perl script uses the [Date::Parse](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Format) and
[Date::Format](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Format) modules from the [TimeDate](https://metacpan.org/release/TimeDate) collection. And some basic arithmetic.

Unfortunately, these modules are not core perl modules, so they are not included with perl.  You'll need to install them yourself.  They are packaged for most distros - e.g. on debian, run `sudo apt-get install libtimedate-perl`.  Otherwise install them with perl's [cpan](https://perldoc.perl.org/cpan) utility (which *is* included with perl).

```perl
$ cat decode-week.pl 
#!/usr/bin/perl -l

use strict;
use Date::Parse;
use Date::Format;

sub reformat_date {
  # parse date from first arg, and tidy it up.
  my ($day, $week, $month, $year) = split /\s*,\s*/, shift;
  $week =~ s/^Week //;  # Don't need that word.
  $day =~ s/^(...).*/$1/; # Only need first three letters.

  # some useful constants
  use constant secs_per_day => 86400;        # close enough
  use constant one_week => secs_per_day * 7;

  # Assumes English. Change as required for other languages.
  my %day_names = (Sun => 0, Mon => 1, Tue => 2, Wed => 3,
                   Thu => 4, Fri => 5, Sat => 6);
  # Alternatively, if you want Monday to be the zeroth weekday.
  #my %day_names = (Mon => 0, Tue => 1, Wed => 2, Thu => 3,
  #                 Fri => 4, Sat => 5, Sun => 6);

  # get time_t for first day of $month $year
  my $t = str2time("1 $month $year");
  # get abbreviated day name for that 1st day
  my $dn = time2str("%a",$t);

  # calculate difference in days
  my $diff = $day_names{$day} - $day_names{$dn};

  if ($week == 1 && $diff < 0) {
      return "Invalid week";
  };

  my $new_t = $t + ($diff * secs_per_day) + (($week-1) * one_week);

  # Date::Format doesn't do %F, use identical %Y-%m-%d instead.
  return time2str("%Y-%m-%d",$new_t);
};


foreach (@ARGV) {
  print "$_ ===> ", reformat_date($_);
};
```

This was written as a function to make it easier to re-use if you want to extract the date to be parsed from a log file or something.  For now, it just takes args from the command line.

Sample output:

```
$ ./decode-week.pl "Monday, Week 1, June, 2022" "Monday, Week 4, June, 2022" "Friday, Week 1, July, 2022"
Monday, Week 1, June, 2022 ===> Invalid week
Monday, Week 4, June, 2022 ===> 2022-06-20
Friday, Week 1, July, 2022 ===> 2022-07-01
```

The subroutine could be improved with some data validation/checking to make sure it's being passed a valid date or, at least, a date in the correct format.  Left as an exercise for the reader, this is a fairly bare-bones example.

Also, the main loop should probably check if the value returned from the function is "Invalid week" or not, rather than just print whatever it receives.

Answer (score 0):

You could tell `ncal` to give you a calendar for the given month and then extract the number in the corresponding row and column (and translate month and day names to numbers) with gawk:

```
#! /bin/sh -
wday=$1 week=$2 month=$3 year=$4
{
  echo "$wday $week $month $year"
  ncal -Shb "$month" "$year"
} | gawk '
  NR == 1 {
    wday = $1; week = $2; month = $3; year = $4
    for (i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
      nday[strftime("%A", (i+2)*86400, 1)] = i
    for (i = 1; i <= 12; i++)
      nmonth[strftime("%B", (i-0.5)*86400*30, 1)] = i
    FIELDWIDTHS = "3 3 3 3 3 3 3"
    next
  }
  NR == 3 + week {
    day = $ nday[wday]
    if (+day) {
      printf "%04d-%02d-%02d\n", year, nmonth[month], day
      ok = 1
    }
    exit
  }
  END {
    if (!ok) {
      print "There is no "wday" in week "week" of "month" "year > "/dev/stderr"
      exit 1
    }
  }'
```

Above month names are interpreted as in per the user's locale.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU awk for time functions, and gensub():

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[, ]+" }
{
    day   = $1
    week  = $3
    month = $4
    year  = $5

    mkMap(year,month)

    key = year SUBSEP month SUBSEP week SUBSEP day
    print $0, "=>", (key in map ? map[key] : "invalid date")
}

function mkMap(year,month,      mthAbbr,mthNr,wkNr,dayNr,date,secs,d) {
    if ( !seen[year,month]++ ) {
        mthAbbr = substr(month,1,3)
        mthNr = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",mthAbbr)+2)/3
        wkNr = 1
        for ( dayNr=1; dayNr<=31; dayNr++ ) {
            date = sprintf("%04d-%02d-%02d", year, mthNr, dayNr)
            secs = mktime(gensub(/-/," ","g",date) " 12 0 0")
            split(strftime("%F,%A",secs),d,",")
            if ( d[1] == date ) {
                # date -> secs -> same date means this is a valid date
                map[year,month,wkNr,d[2]] = date
                wkNr += ( d[2] == "Saturday" ? 1 : 0 )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
Monday, Week 4, June, 2022 (should output: 2022-06-20) => 2022-06-20
Friday, Week 1, July, 2022 (should output: 2022-07-01) => 2022-07-01
Monday, Week 1, June, 2022 (should output: invalid date) => invalid date
```

The above was run against this input file:

```
$ cat file
Monday, Week 4, June, 2022 (should output: 2022-06-20)
Friday, Week 1, July, 2022 (should output: 2022-07-01)
Monday, Week 1, June, 2022 (should output: invalid date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Raku** (formerly known as Perl_6)

```perl
raku -e 'my %months = (Jan => 1, Feb => 2, Mar => 3, Apr => 4, May => 5, Jun => 6, Jul => 7, Aug => 8, Sep => 9, Oct => 10, Nov =>  11, Dec => 12); my %antimonths = %months.antipairs; \
      my %days = (Monday => 1, Tuesday => 2, Wednesday => 3, Thursday => 4, Friday => 5, Saturday => 6, Sunday => 7); my @a; my %antidays = %days.antipairs; \
      my %ordinals = (1 => "st", 2 => "nd", 3 => "rd", 4 => "th", 5 => "th"); \
      for lines.map: *.split(", ") { @a.push( .[3], sprintf( "%02u", %months{.[2].substr(0,3)} ), .[1].substr(*-1,1), %days{.[0]} ) };  \
      my @b = do for @a.rotor(4) { (.[0], .[1], "01").join("-").Date};  \
      my @week-desired = @a[2,6,10...*]; my @DOW-desired = @a[3,7,11...*];  \
      my @offset = do for @b>>.day-of-week Z @DOW-desired -> ($first-of-month_DOW, $DOW-desired) { ($DOW-desired - $first-of-month_DOW) mod 7}; \
      for ([Z] @b, @week-desired, @DOW-desired, @offset) -> ($a,$b,$c,$d) { \
      say "For %antimonths{$a.month}_{$a.year}, the $b%ordinals{$b} %antidays{$c} is:  " ~ $a + $d + 7*($b - 1) };'
```

Sample Input:

```
Saturday, Occurrence 1, January, 2022, #output: 2022-01-01
Monday, Occurrence 1, January, 2022, #output: 2022-01-03
Monday, Occurrence 2, January, 2022, #output: 2022-01-10
Monday, Occurrence 4, June, 2022, #output: 2022-06-27
Friday, Occurrence 1, July, 2022, #output: 2022-07-01
Monday, Occurrence 1, August, 2022, #output: 2022-08-01
```

Sample Output:

```
For Jan_2022, the 1st Saturday is:  2022-01-01
For Jan_2022, the 1st Monday is:  2022-01-03
For Jan_2022, the 2nd Monday is:  2022-01-10
For Jun_2022, the 4th Monday is:  2022-06-27
For Jul_2022, the 1st Friday is:  2022-07-01
For Aug_2022, the 1st Monday is:  2022-08-01
```

The OP posted an interesting question, and I've attempted to answer it 1) using Raku and 2) without using any external modules.

Reading the comments, seems to be some uncertainty regarding the way "week-of-month" should be counted, however. Clearly, a "week" nominally starting on Sunday will give different results than a "week" nominally starting on Monday. Without going into the finer points of "week" calculations, this answer simplifies the "week-of-month" calculation to the ***"nth weekday in the month"***. Correspondingly, the sample input has been changed to reflect `Occurrence` of a particular weekday in the desired month. Hopefully this code will prove useful the OP (and others).

In the first 2 statements (first line) hashes `%months` and `%antimonths` are declared.  In the second 2 statements (second line) hashes `%days` and `%antidays` are declared. In the third statement (third line) hash `%ordinals` is declared. In the fourth statement (fourth line) `lines` are read in from a file, split on `", "` (comma-space), and `push`ed onto the `@a` array, generally from largest time unit first (e.g. years) to smallest (or variable) last. In the fifth statement (fifth line) month and year are extracted out of `@a` and combined to populate `@b` array which consists of valid `ISO-8601` "first-day-of-month" dates.

In the sixth/seventh statements (sixth line), `@a` elements are pulled out to create `@week-desired` and `@DOW-desired` arrays. In the seventh line using `mod` an `@offset` is calculated, which is the number of days from the first-of-the-month to the desired weekday *in the first week of the month*. Finally the offset (in days) and desired-week (desired-week multiplied by 7 to get days) is used in a final calculation to get the `ISO-8601` Date result, which is printed.

*[Note, there's no explicit error-checking: any error-checking will be performed by Raku's `Date` class, which may indeed attempt conversions not desired by the user. Finally, the 'one-liner'-style Raku code posted herein could be re-written into a script, (hopefully) similar to the beautifully-formatted Perl answer posted by @cas].*

https://docs.raku.org/type/Date
https://raku.org